# How to properly instantiate dynamically derived objects and their members in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have currently a seemingly basic problem in C#. I want to instantiate a C# class dynamically. And it shall be either the base class or a derived class.
My problem is, when i try to instantiate a derived class and set the object's properties, the properties are always null. Here is a LINQ-Pad snippet:

```
void Main()
{
    var baseProperty = new BaseProperty() { Name = "TestName" };
    // this one is working, meaning the member Properties != null
    var baseObject = GetObjectInstance<BaseClass, BaseProperty>(baseProperty);
    baseObject.Properties.Dump();

    var derivedProperty = new DerivedProperty() { Name = "TestName", Description = "TestDescription" };
    // this one is not working, meaning derivedObject.Properties is always null
    var derivedObject = GetObjectInstance<DerivedClass, DerivedProperty>(derivedProperty);
    derivedObject.Properties.Dump();
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseProperty Properties { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new DerivedProperty Properties { get; set; }
}

public class BaseProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedProperty : BaseProperty
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public TClass GetObjectInstance<TClass, TProperty>(TProperty properties) 
    where TClass : BaseClass 
    where TProperty : BaseProperty
{
    var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<TClass>();
    myObject.Properties = properties; // this member is always null
    return myObject;
}
```

As soon as I instantiate `derivedObject` and try to set `derivedProperty` of Type `DerivedProperty`, this property is null.

Where am I wrong? How can I solve this? Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding your property with the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) modifier. This means when you call the property on the base type, it's not the same as the property on the derived type. You probably want to use generics to specify the type of your property. For example:

```
public class BaseClass<TProperty> 
    where TProperty : BaseProperty
{
    // Now we have a generic property that must be a BaseProperty
    public TProperty Properties { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedProperty>
{
    // No need for any specific override here any more
}
```

And a slight tweak to your function:

```
public TClass GetObjectInstance<TClass, TProperty>(TProperty properties)
    where TClass : BaseClass<TProperty>
    where TProperty : BaseProperty
{
    var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<TClass>();
    myObject.Properties = properties;
    return myObject;
}
```

Another thing you may want to consider is using the `new()` constraint which means you no longer need to use `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
public TClass GetObjectInstance<TClass, TProperty>(TProperty properties)
    where TClass : BaseClass<TProperty>, new()
    where TProperty : BaseProperty
{
    var myObject = new TClass();
    myObject.Properties = properties;
    return myObject;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks that looks intetesting. I will check that. How easy is it to serialize this class with generics to xml? I guess i will have to implement the IXmlSerializable interface and do the serialization on each derived class, right?

Comment: It's as easy as any other class to serialise.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `new` keyword then you are hiding the method defined in the DerivedClass. And in the GetObjectInstance since you have added a constrained the TClass to be of BaseClass, type of myObject behaves as a BaseClass, and therefore property gets assigned to the BaseClass.Properties.

If you cast the derivedObject to BaseClass then you can see your property is set there.

```
    var derivedProperty = new DerivedProperty() { Name = "TestName", Description = "TestDescription" };
// this one is not working, meaning derivedObject.Properties is always null
var derivedObject = GetObjectInstance<DerivedClass, DerivedProperty>(derivedProperty);
derivedObject.Properties.Dump();
((BaseClass)derivedObject).Properties.Dump();
```

Also, if you need not change the types of the DerivedClass.Properties, you could simply not have the new Property Definition and it should work fine.

```
void Main()
   {
    var baseProperty = new BaseProperty() { Name = "TestName" };
    // this one is working, meaning the member Properties != null
    var baseObject = GetObjectInstance<BaseClass, BaseProperty>(baseProperty);
    baseObject.Properties.Dump();

    var derivedProperty = new DerivedProperty() { Name = "TestName", Description = "TestDescription" };
    // this one is not working, meaning derivedObject.Properties is always null
    var derivedObject = GetObjectInstance<DerivedClass, DerivedProperty>(derivedProperty);
    derivedObject.Properties.Dump();
  }

public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual BaseProperty Properties { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class BaseProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedProperty : BaseProperty
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public TClass GetObjectInstance<TClass, TProperty>(TProperty properties)
    where TClass : BaseClass
    where TProperty : BaseProperty
{
    var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<TClass>();
    myObject.Properties = properties; // this member is always null
    return myObject;
}
```